# Logical statements relating being sunny, wet, windy, having a raincoat, and sweating

Tags: logical-deduction

How do I solve the following?

> If it is sunny, I am wet. If I wear a raincoat, I sweat. When it rains, there is no sun, but I am dry; and when there is wind and no sun, my sweat evaporates. In a rainy day, if it is windy and I wear a raincoat, which one of the following statements is most appropriate?
>
> - (A) I am dry
> - (B) I am wet
> - (C) I sweat
> - (D) I sweat and my sweat evaporates

**Source:** APSC CCE Paper 1, State and Country: Assam, India; Conducted on: 12 September 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given four statements; let's rewrite them in more basic/formal notation.

1. SUNNY implies WET.
2. RAINCOAT implies SWEAT.
3. RAINY implies (DRY and NOT SUNNY).
4. (WINDY and NOT SUNNY) implies SWEAT EVAPORATES.

In the given situation, it is RAINY and WINDY and you wear a RAINCOAT. By 2, you SWEAT. By 3, you are DRY and it is NOT SUNNY. By 4, your SWEAT EVAPORATES. So the answer to your problem could be either **a** or **d**.

Comment: What's wrong with A?

Comment: @msh210 It's possible, but D is the only one that can definitely be deduced. The question asks for "most appropriate" of the four possible answers.

Comment: A can be deduced. You do so in this answer.

Comment: @msh210 Sorry, I think I was confusing WET and DRY. Edited, and ugh, that kind of makes it a bad puzzle.